# C++ Explaining function type

Tags: c++, function, class

This might be a dumb question but in c++ we where given a header file with functions.  My question is does the function have a return type of it does not have ie "int, double, etc". Also i noticed that it does not have void like the other functions do.

```
class Polynomial {

public:
    Polynomial antiderivative(); // No void or type int double ... 

    void add_to_coef(double amount, unsigned int exponent);

    double coefficient(unsigned int exponent) const;
}
```

could someone explain this to me or have a link to a source that explains it. I was looking around but did not know what it is called. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are member functions so they operate on objects of the class `Polynomial`. The one that you single out will return the "antiderivative" (indefinite integral) of the `Polynomial` that it is invoked on. So if you have a `Polynomial` `p`  representing x + c, then `p.antiderivative()` should return a new `Polynomial` representing x^2 / 2 + c * x + d. (Just guessing on the precise semantics of your `Polynomial` class, but that's the general idea, I believe.)

Comment: Okay i think i understand. Thank You

Comment: Integral of x+c should be 0.5x^2+cx+d

Comment: All that math at MIT and can't integrate. Sheesh.

Answer (score 2):

This function has a return type `Polynomial` and no arguments.

Comment: so it would be a return type of the class ?

Comment: Yes, the function will return an instance of the class.